# 2 heads 5 flips weighted coin - what is the probability?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A coin is weighted to 1/12 heads and 11/12 tails.

What is the probability you get exactly 2 heads in 5 coin flips?

I think it's:

(Probability of 2 heads) * (Probability of 3 tails) * (number of ways this can occur)

= (1/12 * 1/12) * (11/12 * 11/12 * 11/12) * (5!/(3!*2!))

= 0.05348990484

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated in the comments, your calculation is correct.